# ¿Cuándo se debe usar el Break en un Switch y cuándo no?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo una duda, he creado una función básica en *JavaScript* y no tengo idea de por qué esta función funciona normalmente con el **break** y sin el **break**. 
¿Cuándo es necesario usar ese **break** en la estructura condicional **switch**?

Esta es la función:

```
function translator( num )
{
    switch ( num )
    {
        case 1:
            return 'one';
        case 2:
            return 'two';
        case 3:
            return 'three';
        case 4:
            return 'four';
        case 5:
            return 'five';
        default:
            return 'Enter a number!';
    }
}

let value = parseInt( prompt( 'Enter the number: ' ) );
let translateValue = translator( value );

document.write( translateValue );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijas en el ejemplo que te pongo a continuación, aquí si es necesario el break:

```js
function translator(num) {
  var result;
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      result = 'one';
      break;
    case 2:
      result = 'two';
      break;
    case 3:
      result = 'three';
      break;
    case 4:
      result = 'four';
      break;
    case 5:
      result = 'five';
      break;
    default:
      result = 'Enter a number!';
  }
  
  return result;
}

let value = parseInt(prompt('Enter the number: '));
let translateValue = translator(value);

document.write(translateValue);
```

El motivo es el siguiente:

- Si pones un return en cada case, la función lo ejecuta y ya no ejecuta las sentencias posteriores.
- Si lo que haces es asignar un valor a una variable, entonces si necesitas el break para que no evalue las demás sentencias.

Resumiendo, el break se usa para que el script salga de la ejecución (en este caso) del switch y no evalúe las demás condiciones.

En mi ejemplo, si quitas los break, verás que el switch evaluará tu número, pero siempre acabará devolviendo el default, pues esa condición también dará true.

Espero haberme explicado correctamente.